# Anchoring text to bottom of custom scrollable label widget in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, chat

Hi i've been trying to create a basic chat in Kivy and followed part of this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmWE2bydekk

New messages are added to the bottom but I have a problem where the text seems to 'float' from the bottom to the top when the user scrolls or the next message is added, after snapping to the bottom. I have made a few modifications from the original code in the video in an attempt to fix it but to no avail.

Full code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label  
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.clock import Clock
          
Window.size = (500, 500)

class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_y=None)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

        self.chat_history = Label(size_hint_y=None, markup=True, halign='left',text_size=(None, None))
        self.chat_history.bind(width=lambda s, w: s.setter('text_size')(s, (w, None)))

        self.scroll_to_point = Label(size_hint_y=None, height=1)

        self.layout.add_widget(self.chat_history)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.scroll_to_point)
    
    def update_chat_history(self, message):
        self.chat_history.text += '\n' + message
        self.chat_history.height = self.chat_history.texture_size[1]
        self.layout.height = self.chat_history.texture_size[1] +15
        self.chat_history.tet_size = (self.chat_history.width*0.98,None)

        self.scroll_to(self.scroll_to_point)
        #self.scroll_to_point.height = 1
        #self.scroll_y = 0
    
class Example(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1,  
                            row_default_height=40,
                            spacing = 10,
                            padding = 10,
                            )
        secondLayout = GridLayout(cols=2, row_force_default=True, row_default_height=40,
                            spacing = 10,
                            )
        self.new_message = TextInput(width=Window.size[0]*0.8,size_hint_x=None, multiline=False)
        submit = Button(text="submit", on_press=self.send_message)
        self.history = ScrollableLabel(height=Window.size[1]*0.9, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.add_widget(self.history)
        secondLayout.add_widget(self.new_message)
        secondLayout.add_widget(submit)
        layout.add_widget(secondLayout)

        initial_messages = ["Hello!", "How are you?", "Test message"]
        for message in initial_messages:
            self.incoming_message(message)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_text_input, 1)

        layout.bind(size=self.adjust_fields)

        return layout
    
    def adjust_fields(self, *_):
        if Window.size[1]*0.1<50:
            new_height=Window.size[1]-50
        else:
            new_height=Window.size[1]*0.9
        self.history.height=new_height

        if Window.size[0]*0.2<160:
            new_width=Window.size[0]-160
        else:
            new_width=Window.size[0]*0.8
        self.new_message.width=new_width
    
    def send_message(self, _):
        message = self.new_message.text
        self.new_message.text=""
        if message:
            self.history.update_chat_history(f"[color=dd2020]You[/color] > {message}")
    
    def focus_text_input(self,_):
        self.new_message.focus = True

    def incoming_message(self, message):
        self.history.update_chat_history(f"[color=20dd20]PowerBot[/color] > {message}")
    
Example().run()
```

The lines that I have tried are the `self.scroll_to_point.height = 1` and `self.scroll_y = 0`, but really I have no clue what im doing.. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is helpful. The basic concept of your code was to put a single Label in a ScrollView and to expand the size of the Label as new messages were added.  This is not a very practical.  There is a texture size limit, and while it would not be an issue in this case it is more common to put widgets in a layout under a scrollview, rather than just growing a Label.

In the code below, I create a Message class, this Message is added to a BoxLayout under the ScrollView.  To position the text at the bottom of the ScrollView, I added Widget to the BoxLayout as a spacer.  Using KV simplifies the code.  It also "automatically" handles setting up the binds, for example the height is set each time a widget is added.  I use BoxLayouts rather than a GridLayout with a single col.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (500, 500)

kv = """
<Message>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    text_size: self.width, None
    size: self.texture_size
    markup: True

BoxLayout:  # was layout
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 10
    ScrollView:
        id: sv
        BoxLayout:
            id: chat
            spacing: 5
            padding: 10
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            Widget: # used as a spacer, push message to bottom
                size_hint_y: None
                height: sv.height
    BoxLayout:  # was second layout
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 40
        spacing: 10
        TextInput:
            id: ti
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: app.send_message(self.text)
        Button:
            text: 'submit'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 75
            on_release: app.send_message(ti.text)
"""


class Message(Label):
    pass


class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def on_start(self):
        initial_messages = ["Hello!", "How are you?", "Test message"]
        for message in initial_messages:
            self.incoming_message(message)
        self.root.ids.sv.scroll_y = 0

    def send_message(self, message):
        self.root.ids.ti.text = ""
        if message:
            m = Message(text=f"[color=dd2020]You[/color] > {message}")
            self.root.ids.chat.add_widget(m)
            self.root.ids.ti.focus = True

    def incoming_message(self, message):
        m = Message(text=f"[color=20dd20]PowerBot[/color] > {message}")
        self.root.ids.chat.add_widget(m)
        self.root.ids.ti.focus = True


ExampleApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you that works much better sir! I think its time I learnt kv as this is so much cleaner